# Eclipse IDE crashs because bash.exe and which.exe on Windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I'm a Java programmer.

I did familiar Eclipse IDE on Windows 7.

It very good but recently when I open Eclipse It runs a moment then crashs(Not Responding).

I'm using JavaEE Developer Eclipse Helios(3.6) and some plugins(subversive, egit, findbug,...)

I tried to solve this problem.

I used Process Explorer tool to show process tree in Windows and saw that Eclipse process has a subprocess is `bash.exe`, `bash.exe` has a subprocess `which.exe`.

This is a picture that I captured from Process Explorer screen.

[image]

I search "`bash.exe` and `which.exe` in Eclipse" but has nothing.

I tried kill `which.exe` and `bash.exe` then Eclipse good running.

Please tell me information about `bash.exe` and `which.exe` in Eclipse IDE and why they crash.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: do your have `cygwin` installed?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.file.net/process/bash.exe.html) link about `bash.exe`. For more info on these files read [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342281) link here about bugs in Eclipse.

Comment: I installed cygwin. bahs.exe and which.exe is located in C:/cygwin/bin/

Comment: You did not tell us what you use eclipse for. If it's not for cygwin development, probably you can remove cygwin from path (if you have it there).

Comment: I have just remove cygwin from path. The problem is fixed. Thanks a lot.